# Using computed field to calculate total hours for a datetime field but to exclude all weekend hours

Tags: datetime

Please please if can anyone help I would really appreciate it!

I have managed to get total hours between value 1 and value 2 of my datetime field however I really want to exclude any hours which are in the weekend. I am creating a timesheet for a group of carers and some people will work from a friday night to a saturday morning etc.

this is my code I use atm for calculating the total hours:

```
$start_value = $entity->field_work_hour_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$end_value = $entity->field_work_hour_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value2'];
$timezone = $entity->field_work_hour_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['timezone'];

$start_date = new DateObject($start_value, $timezone);
$end_date = new DateObject($end_value, $timezone);

$duration = $start_date->difference($end_date, 'hours');
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $duration;
```

I am still quite new to drupal and php so I would really appreciate any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would :

```
$duration = $start_date->difference($end_date, 'hours');
// Place this :
if($start_date->format('Y-W') != $end_date->format('Y-W')) {
  $difweeks = $start_date->difference($end_date, 'weeks');
  $duration = $duration - intval(48 * $difweeks);
}
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $duration;
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help but I am still unable to get this to work. I am unsure if i need to define the $duration first like I have done to work out the total hours (with start date->difference).

Comment: Why not ? It's either that or a `while` loop, so better do that, no ?

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I still can't get this to work though. I am unsure where I need to add this code to my original, i have tried a few combinations but I either get the total hour non dependent on the weekday or 0 hours. any extra help would be amazing and sorry if i am a bit slow working it out!

Comment: sorry just seen your comment. what is a while loop? thanks

Comment: I edited my answer to fit into your code.

Comment: right, i have tried your latest code and I am still getting exactly the same total hours as before. I sort of understand what the code is trying to do but I am totally confused as to why its not working. thanks again for your help!

Comment: $start_value = $entity->field_work_hour_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$end_value = $entity->field_work_hour_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value2'];
$timezone = $entity->field_work_hour_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['timezone'];

$start_date = new DateObject($start_value, $timezone);
$end_date = new DateObject($end_value, $timezone);
$duration = $start_date->difference($end_date, 'hours');
// Place this :
if($start_date->format('Y-W') != $end_date->format('Y-W')) {
  $difweeks = $start_date->difference($end_date, 'weeks');
  $duration = $duration - intval(48 * $difweeks);
}

Comment: sorry that is horrible to look at. its just the code you wrote basically. thanks

Comment: can you dpm() your variable at each step ? Like dpm($duration);, then dpm($difweeks); ?

Comment: do i place the dpm($duration); as a seperate line after the $duration line for example?

Comment: also i still have the first computed field calculating the total hours irrespective of the weekdays, would this interfere with the second calculated field we are trying to get working?